# How do I make procedural volumetric planetary clouds?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, procedural, volumetrics

So, I’m making a procedurally generated planet in blender, and I need a way to make realistic looking volumetric clouds that look good from both space, and the surface. Even if I use a sphere around the planet for the clouds (not volumetric), then I would need to figure out how to actually make that iconic cloud shape. The clouds on earth twist and turn, making formations that are hard to describe. I want to mimic that look in blender 100% procedurally volumetricly. When I add non-volumetric clouds right now, they just don’t feel right. They look vaguely similar to clouds, but they lack that twisting and variety. You can only do so much with a noise node and some transparent nodes plus a color ramp and some mix shaders.

Comment: i recommend at least adding an image to your question how you want it to look like

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186597/does-anyone-knows-how-to-make-spiral-clouds-hurricane-for-a-planet https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220679/artifacts-in-cycles-clouds-and-volumetric-atmosphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111462/planetary-atmospheric-volumetric-clouds https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45484/render-of-planet-earth-in-blender-render-and-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31424/planet-texture-generator https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7509/atmosphere-rayleigh-mie-scattering-in-cycles